# MongoDb: embeding vs reference

Tags: mongodb, schema

I have the following collections:

- **Client** contains Product contains Project contains Task and
- **Company** contains Subsidiary contains Department contains Users (and user contains custom properties)

**What is the best practice? How to use mongodb more efficiently?**

As for me, **Users** and **Projects** will be changed more often and should be defined as separate collections.

What is your advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no unified answer for you question, as MongoDB allows you to do both embedding and reference. 
But here are some tips: don't bloat a collection, because querying the elements deep below might be hard, especially if you're going to use lists.

If you are able to prototype, try embedding the collections first and then write a unit test which will add/remove/query projects and users. If that would work, then there's no need to reference them.

Comment: how about the index? will i be able to make an index for example on db.Company.enshureIndex('subsidiary.departament.user.name.lastname')?

Comment: Sure, why not? See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-IndexingonEmbeddedKeys(%22DotNotation%22)

Comment: how about the speed? what will be faster? separate collections and linking vs big documents?

Comment: That's where 'it depends' starts. MongoDB is document-oriented, so it meant to be fast with documents, no matter what the size is. And as long, as you use indexes, performance should not differ for the approaches at all. Although, these could be crucial factors if you scale horizontally, i.e. keeping collections on separate hosts.